# TSQL Optional Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Query that is pulling in data for the current month for my by default. I then have a "Filter" option on my page where they can enter in some data to filter the content by and re-run the query.

I have my select statement working for the current month however I am not quite sure how to implement the logic for fields that do not contain content.

Example: If the user fills in the start and end date in the filter options it needs to use those dates vs the default ones of Current month/year.

The tricky part for me is the department and category. If there is a value in the filter, it needs to look up submissions just on those values `category=3` `department=5`. However, when there those are empty on the filter settings, it needs to ignore the category and department and get me the record regardless of what the value is.

Here is my current SP:

```
 IF (@action = 'filter')
            BEGIN
                SELECT A.[submissionID],
                       A.[subEmpID],
                       A.[nomineeEmpID],
                       CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[submissionDate], 101) AS submissionDate,
                       A.[situation],
                       A.[task],
                       A.[action],
                       A.[result],
                       A.[timestamp],
                       A.[statusID],
                       A.[approver],
                       A.[approvalDate],
                       B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] AS nomineeName,
                       B.[ntid] AS nomineeNTID,
                       B.[qid] AS nomineeQID,
                       C.[FirstName] + ' ' + C.[LastName] AS submitName,
                       C.[ntid] AS submitNTID,
                       D.[categoryName]
                FROM   empowermentSubmissions AS A
                       INNER JOIN
                       empTable AS B
                       ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[empID]
                       INNER JOIN
                       empTable AS C
                       ON A.[subEmpID] = C.[empID]
                       INNER JOIN
                       empowermentCategories AS D
                       ON A.[categoryID] = D.[catID]
                WHERE  DATEPART(m, A.[submissionDate]) = MONTH(getdate())
                       AND DATEPART(yyyy, A.[submissionDate]) = YEAR(getdate())
                FOR    XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
            END
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you check the value of the POST first?  If it's blank, set it to a default.

Comment: I can do that but how would it work for department / category? There is no default value in the table. All would be cat 1,2,3,4,5 where a defined category would be `where cat = 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at *"If there is a value in the filter, it needs to look up submissions just on those values category=3 department=5. However, when there those are empty on the filter settings, it needs to ignore the category and department and get me the record regardless of what the value is."*

So let say you have filter value in parameter called `@Filter` you can do something like below

```
Where (@Filter is null OR (@Filter is not null and category=3 and department=5))
```

**Update**

Didn't notice you have two parameters

```
Where (@category is null or (category = @category))
      and (@department is null or (department= @department))
```

Comment: To clarify; the category and department are dynamic values chosen from the UI it self.  `@category` and `@department` are the two variables. If those are not set, it needs to include all records regardless of the value in those fields in the DB. If it is set, it uses those values.

Comment: @SBB: Ok, updated the answer, but I am not sure what you mean by "*If there is a value in the filter, it needs to look up submissions just on those values category=3 department=5*". can you please explain? Are you passing `@category=3 and @department=5` ?

Comment: By filter, I mean the UI filter options. They could filter by 1 item or fill out everything. I will set the dates manually if they don't enter them however my issue was selecting all the data for category / department if the value was null on the front end

Comment: trying to fix my code, seems like it is sending an empty value not a null value

Comment: @SBB: you mean empty string like '' ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need the query hardcoded in sql try:

```
where (category = @category or @category is null)
```

and keep that format for all the variables.  If a category is provided, then it filters on the provided value.  Otherwise all the rows are returned since the parameter is null.

If you can dynamically build the sql query, either in code or in sql itself, use an if statement.

```
if(@category is not null)
begin
set @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'category = @category'
end
```

Comment: This was almost working but I think I have an issue with my SP getting an empty value from the var, not a null value. Trying to fix that now to test

Comment: @SBB It is easiest if you get a null value into the SP but if not you can change IS NULL to = ''

Answer (score 0):

How about parameters @Category and @Department:

```
WHERE (@Category IS NULL OR @Category = Category)
AND (@Department IS NULL OR @Department = Department)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I'd define a variable ahead of time (in this case @filter), and depending on the frequency of the query, use pattern matching in the where or join clause:**

**** EDITED :: This is by no means a performance-driven solution.****

```
/* Creating temp table or example query */
IF OBJECT_id('TempDB..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    [category] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [description] VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Temp
  SELECT *
  FROM (
  VALUES
  ('Users', 'Joe'),
  ('Users', 'Laura'),
  ('Developers', 'Mike'),
  ('Developers', 'Jane'),
  ('Analysts', 'Jimmy'),
  ('Analysts', 'Monica')) AS vtable
  ([category], [description])

DECLARE @filter VARCHAR(20)
SET @filter = 'Dev'
SET @filter = ISNULL(@filter, '')

SELECT *
FROM #Temp
WHERE category LIKE '%' + @filter + '%'
   OR description LIKE '%' + @filter + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameter in T-SQL

```
 declare @ID varchar(4) = '1001';
-- declare @ID varchar(4) = '';
-- declare @ID varchar(4) = null;



 Select * from YourTable t
 Where
 t.ID > 0
 and (IsNull(@ID,'') = '' or t.ID = @ID)
```